# Linq query construction based on empty parameters

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamicquery

I have an object like this:

```
public class Filters
{
    List<string> A { get; set; }
    List<string> B { get; set; }
}
```

I will use it as parameters of a function that will execute a query on a Database.
These itens, A and B, will indicate the "where" filters.

Look at the following code:

```
//Filters Initialization
Filters TestFilters = new Filters();
TestFilters.A = new List<string>();
TestFilters.B = new List<string>(new string[] {"testfilter1","testfilter2"}); //WHERE B == "testfilter1" OR B == "testfilter2"

//Call of the function that executes SELECT on DB
List<Table> Result = TestFunction(TestFilter);
```

The function:

```
public static List<Table> TestFunction(Filters pParameter)
{
    ExampleDataContext dc = new ExampleDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.ExampleConnectionString);
    List<Table> SelectResult = new List<Table>();

    if (pParameter.A.count != 0 && pParameter.B.count != 0)

        SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
            where pParameter.A.Contains(x.A)
            where pParameter.B.Contains(x.B)
            select x).ToList();

    else if (pParameter.A.count == 0 && pParameter.B.count != 0)
    {
        SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
            where pParameter.B.Contains(x.B)
            select x).ToList();
    }

    else if (pParameter.A.count != 0 && pParameter.B.count == 0)
    {
        SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
            where pParameter.A.Contains(x.A)
            select x).ToList();
    }

    else if (pParameter.A.count == 0 && pParameter.B.count == 0)
    {
        SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
            select x).ToList();
    }       

    return SelectResult;
}
```

Sometimes A or/and B is/are empty, then I am using "IF" structure to handle it. 
Maybe I could face a problem where my filter is bigger, more than 2 parameters, and it would be difficult/boring to code.
My question is: It is working, but is there another way to do it, instead of using IF?

Comment: you should use chained linq query, that is to old query result continued with new query. you should not query on x every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some of the options, but unsucessfully.
Below you can find the code that worked for me:

```
List<Table> SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
                            where (pParameter.A.Count != 0 ? pParameter.A.Contains(x.A) : true)
                            where (pParameter.B.Count != 0 ? pParameter.B.Contains(x.B) : true)
                            select s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try(chained linq), I just rewrite by hand and did not compile or run:

```
        public static List<Table> TestFunction(Filters pParameter)
    {
        ExampleDataContext dc = new ExampleDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.ExampleConnectionString);
        var SelectResult = dc.Table;

        if (pParameter.A.count != 0)
            SelectResult = from x in SelectResult 
                           where pParameter.A.Contains(x.A)
                           select x;

        if (pParameter.B.count != 0)
        {
            SelectResult = from x in SelectResult
                           where pParameter.B.Contains(x.B)
                           select x;
        }
        return SelectResult.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SelectResult = (from x in dc.Table
            where pParameter.A.Any() && pParameter.A.Contains(x.A)
            where pParameter.B.Any() && pParameter.B.Contains(x.B)
            select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is straightforward. Just use correct LINQ syntax.

```
//Parameters class
public Class Parameters
{
    public List<string> A {get; set;}
    public List<int> B {get; set;}
}

//some function in a controller
public List<SomeResult> GetResult(Parameters pars)
{
    var db = new DbContext();
    var result = db.SomeResult.Where(s => s.Any(p =>p.SomeString == pars.A
                   || p.SomeInt == pars.B))
            .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried it, but "Any" is not available. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

with `IQueryable<Table>` (type of `dc.Table` and `dc.Table.Where()`), you can chain criteria, and export ToList only in buttom line.

so if yoy change the `SelectResult` from `List<Table>` to `IQueryable<Table>`,
each criteria can be chained to the previous expression, and it is done as though AND:

```
public static List<Table> TestFunction(Filters pParameter)
{
    ExampleDataContext dc = new ExampleDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.ExampleConnectionString);

    //all
    IQueryable<Table> SelectResult = dc.Table;

    //add conditions
    if (pParameter.A.count != 0 )
        SelectResult = SelectResult.Where(x => pParameter.A.Contains(x.B));
    if (pParameter.B.count != 0)
        SelectResult = SelectResult.Where(x => pParameter.A.Contains(x.B));

    //export, with one\two\zero conditions
    return SelectResult.ToList();
}
```

If your case is more complex (such as multiple conditions and with OR operators) consider using the wonderful tool [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).